# Merging 2 fields in a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, mobileconnect

Customer has a data extension named SMS_Sends_DE, this data extension stores SMSTracking Information. If the SMS message is greater that 160 characters, there will be 2 records in the data extension.

For example, if you send the following SMS message "A text can hold up to 160 characters. If your message goes over 160 characters, you'll actually be sending multiple texts. It's fine if you send messages with more than 160 characters - they'll look the same to everyone as if you only sent one." Since it is more than 160 characters, it will have 2 records in the data extension

Mobile: 123456
MessageText: A text can hold up to 160 characters. If your message goes over 160 characters, you'll actually be sending multiple texts. It's fine if you send messages

Mobile: 123456
MessageText: with more than 160 characters - they'll look the same to everyone as if you only sent one.

Customer wants to know if there is a way of combining these 2 rows and saving them as one record in another data extension.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply write an SQL Query to do this:

```
SELECT 
concat(field1,field2) AS combinedField
FROM SMS_Sends_DE
```